# Increasing spacing between labels for geom_line plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel, direct-labels

Suppose I have some set of lines that I plot using `ggplot` and `geom_line`. I want to label these lines. I can do this using `geom_dl` from the `directlabels` package, but even with the provided method to avoid overlaps (e.g. `"last.qp"`), I still think that the labels are two close together.

How can I increase the spacing between these labels (here, in the y direction), *without* manually specifying each of their locations using `ggplot2::annotate` or something similar? I'm open to answers that don't involve the `directlabels` package, but if possible I'd like to stick with it because it does 95% of the work of labeling lines quite well.

There's potentially a hint [here](http://directlabels.r-forge.r-project.org/docs/utility.function/posfuns/qp.labels.html) in `tiebreak.big`, but I couldn't get it to work...

```
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(directlabels)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble(x = 1:10) %>%
  mutate(y1 = x^2) %>%
  mutate(y2 = y1+0.5) %>%
  gather(key = var, value = value, y1, y2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value, color = var)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_dl(aes(label = var), method = list(cex = 1.2, dl.trans(x = x + 0.2), "last.qp"))
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: have you looked at the `ggrepel` package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggrepel/vignettes/ggrepel.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the `ggrepel` package. It has lots of options for customisation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(ggrepel)

data <- tibble(x = 1:10) %>%
  mutate(y1 = x^2) %>%
  mutate(y2 = y1+0.5) %>%
  gather(key = var, value = value, y1, y2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value, color = var)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = var),
                  nudge_x = 1,
                  force = 1,
                  box.padding = 1,
                  segment.alpha = .5,
                  data = data %>%
                    group_by(var) %>% 
                    filter(x == max(x)))
```

[image]

You may want to play around with `force` and `box.padding` parameters.

Comment: This works great. Using the `segment.alpha = 0` and `direction = "y"` parameters eliminates the lines and makes it easier to align the labels as well.